# redirect same sub by slash in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect as:

```
Redirect 301 /ruler/             http://www.sample.com/ruler/
Redirect 301 /ruler/red/review   http://www.sample.com/product_review/flexible-ruler/
Redirect 301 /ruler/read/        http://www.sample.com/read/soft-ruler/
```

with above code, it not work correct. with 
    `Redirect 301 /ruler/red/review` will to `http://www.sample.com/ruler/`

Thanks about helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `Redirect 301 /ruler/red/review` line before `Redirect 301 /ruler/`, read more about [Order of Processing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#order)